# Overriding/Overwriting a function in javascript

Tags: javascript

There is a function in a javascript library I want to override for my own use case, I want to use most of the code from the function but add some extra functionality. In my console I can access the function by doing, `somelibrary.CharCounter.prototype.count` this function takes an argument of text.

I have tried the following,

```
somelibrary.CharCounter.prototype.count = (function(_super, text) {
   return function(_super, apply) {
       console.log("overwriting", text);
       return _super.apply(this, arguments);
   };
})(somelibrary.CharCounter.prototype.count)
```

On the above I get the the console.log as I would expect, but I also get this error,

> Uncaught typeerror: _super.apply is not a function

Obvioulsy I am doing something wrong, all I want to do is ovveride the function so it returns something different to it's original method.

Comment: Fixed version: https://jsfiddle.net/Lvpz1wf9/

Answer (score 1):

---

You have to pass `_super` to the outer function only and make the inner function accept the "super" arguments:

```js
Array.prototype.slice = (function(_super) {
   return function(x, y) {
       console.log("overwriting", x, y);
       return _super.apply(this, arguments);
   };
})(Array.prototype.slice);


console.log([1,2,3,4,5,6].slice(1,3))
```

To avoid repetitions, you might want to define a generic function:

```js
function override(obj, method, fn) {
    let prev = obj[method]

    obj[method] = function (...args) {
        return fn.call(
            this,
            prev.bind(this),
            ...args,
        )
    }
}


override(Array.prototype, 'slice', function (_super, x, y) {
    console.log("overwriting", x, y);
    return _super(x, y + 1)
})


console.log([1,2,3,4,5,6].slice(1,3))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) for this. Here is a demo on proxying `Math.sin`:

```js
Math.sin = new Proxy(Math.sin, {
    apply: function(original, thisArg, args) {
        console.log(`Executing ${original.name}(${args.join()})`);
        return original.apply(thisArg, args);
    }
});

console.log(Math.sin(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe slightly more readable solution:

```
somelibrary.CharCounter.prototype.foo = (function () {
  var _super = somelibrary.CharCounter.prototype.foo;
  return function (text) {
    console.log("overwriting", text);
    return _super.apply(this, arguments);
  }
})();
```

It is also possible to define generic `extendFunction()` function for overriding functions:

```
function extendFunction(superFunc, overridingFunc) {
  return function () {
    overridingFunc.call(this, superFunc, arguments);
  }
}

somelibrary.CharCounter.prototype.foo = extendFunction(
  somelibrary.CharCounter.prototype.foo,
  function (superFunc, args) {
    console.log("overwriting", args);
    return superFunc.apply(this, args);
  }
);
```